# Invalid categories

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I created a sub-category using an ampersand in its name. I somehow managed to successfully place this category into another category and now I'm unable to remove it.

To further complicate this matter, I created another sub-category that has the same prefix:

```
Category: Product
  Category: Features & Design
  Category: Features
```

Clicking on `Features & Design` simply takes me to `Features`. How do I remove the `Features & Design` from the `Product` category?

Comment: Please give more information. What application are you talking about?

Comment: It seems safe to assume he's talking about mediawiki, judging by the tags and the content of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I resolved the problem:

- Browse to the category containing the ampersand. Notice that the URL does contain the additional path information: `Features_%26_Design`.
- Choose to edit. Notice that the edit path does not include the path information. If you manually add it in, then you'll be able to edit the correct page.
- I then added a [redirect](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aRedirect) to the category I wanted to remove: `#REDIRECT [[:Category:Glossary]]`